# Is there a way to search for an item in a ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewBag.People made up from a View;

```
 var query = db.Vw_INTERACTPEOPLE.Select(p => new { p.PersonID, p.Fullname });
 ViewBag.People = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "PersonID", "FullName");
```

Which all works fine, but in my view I have another model populating a table, and one of the items is populates is an JobcontactID (textbox) which links to the PersonID (i didnt design the database). So I want to search the viewbag for the ID and rather than displaying it I want to display the persons  Fullname,  so is there any viewbag search functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewBag` is just a `dynamic` wrapper around `ViewData` (which allows the property invoked at runtime to become the key which will be used to look up the value in `ViewData`). You can query `ViewData` like this:

```
SelectList peopleSelectList = (from pair in ViewData
                               where pair.Key == "People"
                               select pair.Value);
```

**Update** So you wish to query the select list itself?

Here's a function defined in the razor view:

```
@functions {
    public string FindPersonName(string id)
    {
        return (from item in ViewBag.People as SelectList
                where item.Value == id
                select item.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

@functions.FindPersonName(jobContactId)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply, 
I am trying to simply do a look up in viewbag to get a persons name from the Id and display the name rather than the ID.
this may help explain what I am trying to do.
          <td>

        @if (item.JobcontactID.ToString() == "")
        { 
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobcontactID ) 
              
        }
        else
        { 
Get the JobcontactID and search the Viewbag.People(peopleID) and display the     associated name.
        }

Comment: @HackedByChinese, this is the Biggest haack that i saw in last couple of days.

Comment: Heh, it's not much of a hack. Not my preference (I do agree the viewmodel should be prepared with all it needs at the controller), but better advice means a better understanding of OP's model and views. I suppose I was more just interested in explaining the relationship of `ViewBag` to `ViewData` to OP.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to pass that information in your ViewModel. It will keep it clean and maintainable in long run. Here is a good post: [Use ViewModels to manage data & organize code in ASP.NET MVC applications](http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications)

Comment: sorry for the delay was looking into the link makes a lot of sense, this is my first MCV project, think I will be using the ViewModel a bit more now.

Comment: @chris, no problem. We are all learning together. If you liked my answer, you may mark it as solution though ;)