# Is there a data annotation I can use to prevent a property from appearing in my views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The model classes are generated, using T4 templates, from an EF entity model. I have partial model classes whose sole purpose is to add a `[MetadataType(typeof(xxxMetdata))]` attribute to the model classes. Last, I have a class (xxxMetadata) which contains my data annotations (display names, formatting,etc.). A typical model is named TestABC123 and its metadata class, is named TestABC123Metadata

How do I annotate my metadata class to prevent a specific property from being generated / appearing in my CRUD views? I know I could delete the properties after the views have been generated but I'd rather the properties just not be generated in the first place.

I'm using MVC 4 RC with EF.

Thanks!

Update 1 -

Here is my partial class...

```
namespace XXX.Web.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TestAbcMetadata))]
    public partial class TestAbc
    {
    }
}
```

Here is my metadata class...

```
namespace XXX.Web.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class TestAbcMetadata
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int TestTypeId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Visit Number")]
        [Required]
        public int VisitId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I tried adding  `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` to one of the properties in a metadata class but that property still appears in the generated view code. Thoughts?

Comment: Just a clarification... are you using EditorForModel?  I believe the ScaffoldColumnAttribute only influences that method, not other HTML helpers.

Comment: how are you rendering your viewmodel, how your view look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Create **ViewModels for your View**. These are plain POCO you will use to handle your Views.

Ex :

```
public class AddUser
{
  public string EmailAddress { set;get;}
  public string Age { set;get;}
}
```

And use these ViewModels to transfer data between your controller actions and views

```
public ActionResult GetThat()
{
  var addUserVM=new AddUser();
  return View(addUserVM);
}
```

You can keep the Classes generated by EF as it is. Those represent your Domain model. But viewmodels are for your Views. It may look similar. But not always.

You may need a mapping layer to map your Domain object classes to your ViewModels as required. You may consider using libraries like **AutoMapper** for this or write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a view-model from scratch and map your model to this view-model by excluding the property that you do not want to appear on your view.

Try something like the following in your viewmodel:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Here is a good post that will clarify your question: [What is an ASP.NET MVC ViewModel?](http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications)

You may find it useful to refer to the previous post and discussion: [Search for an item in a ViewBag or use ViewModel instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049218/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-an-item-in-a-viewbag)